# React createContext and useContext issue

Tags: reactjs

So I just realized that having my Context provider out in App() was running all this time every time I changed routes. Logically makes sense but not sure why it never crossed my mind. The issue with this is that it api calls every time with useEffect even though I don't need it unless I'm in the components that actually use it.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Header />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={AddClient} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/add-client" component={AddClient} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/client-list" component={ClientList} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/promo-codes" component={Promo} />
        <TasksProvider>
          <PrivateRoute path="/task-manager" component={TaskManager} />
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/task-manager/:id" component={Modal} />
        </TasksProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```

I initially tried just managing a single state in TaskManager and prop passing from TaskManager into Modal component since it was only one level deep  but both these components use socket.io to do realtime magic(?) and just kept re-rendering and running into issues (too long a story). So just having a context provider do all the state managing worked in the end.

Currently, I just stuffed a

```
if (!window.location.pathname.includes("/task-manager") return;
```

into every useEffect in the TasksProvider to avoid the issue. So the question is, what other options do I have to maintain a similar structure and not let the provider run everytime?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation,

> A component calling useContext will always re-render when the context
> value changes. If re-rendering the component is expensive, you can
> optimize it by using memoization.

To prevent the API calls or other expensive computations to be triggered, you need to put them in useMemo or memo. This ensure that they are recomputed only if there dependencies (the argument passed into them) changes. Find out more here https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15156#issuecomment-474590693